# Verificar ultimo registro de uma tabela sql

Tags: php, sql

Boa galera, seguinte ... Eu estou tentando pegar o ultimo registro de uma tabela com uma id

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Só que ele n ta retornando o último registro, ele está percorrendo toda a tabela atrás de um registro, Alguém pode me dizer como que faço isso? 
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isso funciona bem mas add uma coluna repetuindo o id que vc pode suprimir
ou usar subquery

```
SELECT MAX(collummID),* FROM tabela
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou do jeito que eu queria!

Answer (score 2):

A cláusula `WHERE` vai restringir a busca ao número que você colocar em `?`. A *query* correta nesse caso seria:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

A resposta acima está correta, quando você define o `id` (ou qualquer campo da tabela), a consulta só trará o que tiver aquele valor especificado.

Existem algumas alternativas à solução proposta que você pode ver lá no [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp):

**TOP:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tabela ORDER BY id;
```

**ROWNUM:**

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```